# Как получить доступ к содержимому json-строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть json-строка:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":{
        "BKK":{
            "origin":"IEV",
            "destination":"BKK",
            "price":7936,
            "transfers":1,
            "airline":"FZ",
            "flight_number":730,
            "departure_at":"2017-01-16T03:20:00Z",
            "return_at":"2017-03-08T12:10:00Z",
            "expires_at":"2016-12-29T12:07:13Z"
        },
        "DXB":{
            "origin":"IEV",
            "destination":"DXB",
            "price":2378,
            "transfers":0,
            "airline":"FZ",
            "flight_number":728,
            "departure_at":"2017-01-12T14:25:00Z",
            "return_at":"2017-01-31T19:55:00Z",
            "expires_at":"2016-12-29T18:48:32Z"
        }
    },
    "error":null,
    "currency":"UAH"
}
```

И когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к значению поля, например, origin, то получаю ошибку **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined**
:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pwf.append('<div class="text">Пункт отправки:' + json.data[i].origin + '</div>');
}
```

Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что у массивов данных разные ключи, но как решить проблему - не знаю.

Answer (score 5):

`json.data` не массив, а обычный объект. Можно пройтись по всем его свойствам:

```
for (var p in json.data) {
    pwf.append('<div class="text">Пункт отправки:' + json.data[p].origin + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: А можно как-то сконвертировать JS-объект в json-массив?

Comment: Можно, но это будет намного сложнее. Я так понимаю, JSON приходит из какого то внешнего сервиса, на который вы не влияете? Или есть возможность исправить то, что приходит? Кстати, в JSON-коде выше не хватает 1 закрывающей скобочки.

Comment: Да. Я получаю json-строку от API и мне в принципе удобнее работать с json напрямую, чем с объектами.